# Deploy multiple webapps in parallel with Jetty 9.4.x

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

[This web page](http://blog.activeeon.com/2015/01/speeding-up-web-app-deployment-in-jetty.html) suggests its possible to deploy webapps in parallel, using this function:

```
HandlerList handlerList = createHandlerList(...);
handlerList.setParallelStart(true);
```

I can't find anything similar in Jetty 9.4.x and Google seems to return little either.

How can I do this with the latest Jetty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel startup of Handler Collections were removed in...

- Jetty 7.6.13.v20130916
- Jetty 8.1.14.v20131031
- Jetty 9.0.0.v20130308

.. as it was known to cause problems with LifeCycle startup.

The original reason for the parallel start was to improve startup performance.

Since Jetty 9.2.2.v20140723, the [jetty-quickstart concepts](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html) were introduced that allows for a compile time scan of the webapp that produces a `WEB-INF/quickstart-web.xml` which allows for static load of the webapp (no bytecode scanning, no annotation scanning, no discovery of the Servlet spec components occur).